# Which Google Drive PHP API version to use?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

So I am trying to create a PHP app that interacts with Google Drive. Going through their DOC as well as some of the questions here in SO, I see there are a few versions available:

1. GitHub Version: `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client`
   This is BETA, however it is officially developed by Google and many of the code samples in developer.google.com refers to this.
2. SVN version: `http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk`
   In the quick start documentation, it says to get the PHP SDK from this SVN location. It is referred to in some docs, but not all.

The SVN version and GIT versions are different. For eg if you consider the `Google_Client` class..

in GIT, location of the class is `Google/Client.php`

In SVN, location of the class is `Google_Client.php`

The code contained within the files are also different, though not by much.

I am very confused which one to use!! Has anyone worked on this before? Can anyone give me any pointers. Your answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [Googlecode homepage](http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/). It says:

> This repository is deprecated, please see the latest on GitHub

So I will suggest to use the Github version. Also since the GitHub version has had an update 8 hours ago. Which means it's an up-to-date library.

Comment: So I guess they deprecated the library and replaced it with a beta :| Wonder what google is up to... Thanks for your answer!